# Sign concatenated PDF in append mode with CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I tried to sign PDF with append mode and certification level CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED but certain PDF files shown as modified and therefore invalid in Acrobat.

itext 5.5.6, code:

```
PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os,'\0',null,true);
PdfSignatureAppearance app = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
app.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
```

PDf file is created with **wkhtmltopdf** and concatenated with itself with **pdfunite** (CentOS 7)

Here is zip with sample PDF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lea6r9fup6th44c/test_pdf.zip?dl=0

g.pdf - original PDF
2g.pdf - concatenated version (`pdfunite g.pdf g.pdf 2g.pdf`)
signed_g.pdf - original signed file, looks OK in Acrobat
signed_2g.pdf - concatenated signed file, looks like corrupted in Acrobat

[image]

So is it correct behavior, or something goes wrong with Acrobat, pdfunite, itext or myself )))?

Thanks.

Comment: Verifying with different tools one gets that the signature is valid. Something like this usually happens with documents which cause Adobe Reader to manipulate the document upon startup. In such a case Adobe Reader checks the changed document and, therefore, sees an invalid signature.

Comment: An interesting case, will look into it some more later.  One issue in 2g.pdf is an invalid **Size** in the **trailer**, it says 110 while the highest object number is 129. But fixing this does not suffice.

Comment: Probably pdfunite merges files wrong. If you discover what exactly happens it's possible to open bug for it. They really react )

Comment: As mentioned one issue is the **Size** entry, but there likely are more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certifying the sample [2g.pdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/2g.pdf) using the OP's code and verifying the result with other tools than Adobe Reader one obtains the information that the certification signature is valid.

Something like this (i.e. Adobe Reader complaining about a perfectly valid signature) usually happens with documents which cause Adobe Reader to manipulate the document upon loading. In such a case Adobe Reader checks the signatures in the changed document and, therefore, sees an invalid signature. Such manipulations may especially be repairs of invalid files.

This also is the case here, [2g.pdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/2g.pdf) is not completely valid (even though in a way that PDF parsers usually ignore): Its cross reference table is segmented into multiple subsections:

```
xref
0 1
0000000001 65535 f
3 2
0000000015 00000 n
0000000107 00000 n
6 41
0000000146 00000 n
...
0000015682 00000 n
48 14
0000015864 00000 n
...
0000025433 00000 n
66 2
0000025455 00000 n
0000025548 00000 n
69 41
0000025588 00000 n
...
0000041144 00000 n
111 14
0000041327 00000 n
...
0000050929 00000 n
126 4
0000050952 00000 n
0000051004 00000 n
0000051075 00000 n
0000051242 00000 n
```

But segmented cross reference tables are valid only in case of incremental updates, not in case of initial document revisions, and this document is constructed as an initial revision.

> For a file that has never been incrementally updated, the cross-reference section shall contain only one subsection, whose object numbering begins at 0.
>
> *(section 7.5.4 Cross-Reference Table of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Thus, this segmented table is invalid.

So I fixed the cross reference table to contain but one sub-section (by adding **f** (ree) entries for the indices left out: [2g-fix.pdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/2g-fix.pdf) . And indeed, certifying this document using the OP's code one gets a certification signature Adobe Reader (at least version XI I've currently installed here) is happy with.

So this is the disadvantage of using incremental updates: One keeps the errors of the original document and has to cope with them...

Comment: So it's pdfunite bug, that can be reported, right? By a way, what other PDF tools can verify signatures?

Comment: *So it's pdfunite bug* - yes, it is. It hardly ever causes a problem but here it does. *what other PDF tools can verify signatures* - There are numerous web services to start with, and then many PDF libraries offer the means for PDF signature verification

Comment: Actually it's not bug, it's feature ))). Here is line `writeXRefTableTrailer(trailerDict, yRef, gFalse /* do not write unnecessary entries */` in pdfunite.cc.  Changing **gFalse** to **gTrue** and removing **not** from comment )) fixes the problem.

Comment: *Actually it's not bug, it's feature* - Well, that feature ***is* a bug**.