# Document has been altered or corrupted

Tags: java, pdfbox, aspose

i have one example of PDF [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yifcskspv13il0e/Merged_document.pdf?dl=0), process signed with `PDFBox 2.0.25` after i sign, process validation `AddValidationInformation` but only this document encountered an error `Document has been altered or corrupted`. the PDF was created online with `https://products.aspose.app/`.

code example i use for signing from here `https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature2.java`

[image: Example pdf error]

any suggest ?

Comment: The most common error is tranporting the PDF not as binary **application/octet-stream** or such, but as **text/...** which will corrupt the original PDF.

Comment: transporting before signing or after signing the PDF ?

Comment: I remember some problems with Aspose PDFs, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68801701/  I haven't had the time to look at your PDF so maybe Aspose is innocent.

Comment: Indeed, just as @Tilman pointed out as possibility, the original PDF file is invalid (in a very minor way) which in signing contexts can result in Adobe Acrobat claiming "altered or corrupted" contents. As mentioned in the answer Tilman referred to, creating PDFs with this (minor) error has been a bug in Aspose software for many years. You can fix the file by loading it with PDFBox and saving it right away.

Comment: Ok, I'll close your question as duplicate of other questions dealing with failed verifications in Adobe Acrobat due to invalid initial cross reference table.